# Can't get facebook like button to sit flush to the right

Tags: css, facebook-like

See http://unlockinglg.com/beta3/index.html#

I tried inspecting and I can't seem to find a margin and padding that would make a difference.

[image]

Comment: This is a very common problem with the Facebook Like button if you Google it. I've worked around this problem before by simply changing the design of where the buttons are situated.

Comment: Here's a possible solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743036/right-align-the-contents-of-a-facebook-like-button-iframe

Answer (score 0):

I can only see one 'hack' of a solution. Use a negative `margin-right` on the whole element to counteract the apparent bug in the rendering engine that makes the `<div>` 8 pixels bigger than the `<table>`.